# Using a ternary expression inside append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda

I trying to using ternary expression inside the jQuery `append()`. I have checked in the console and no error was showing. The problem is that the `tr` doesn't append to `tbody`.

```
$(".invoice table tbody").append("<tr> \
    <td> <span class=''>" + price.toFixed(0) == 0 ? Obs : 1 + "</span></td> \
    <td> <span class=''>" + price.toFixed(2) + "</span> </td> \
    <td> <input type='checkbox' name='removeItem' class='removeItemCheckBox'/></td> \
</tr>");
```

Comment: "something is wrong". What? You have to explain the incorrect behavior for us to help you.

Comment: Where exactly is there a "lambda expression" in that code?

Comment: @Pointy I think OP means 'ternary', not 'lambda'.

Comment: i mean this condition: price.toFixed(0) == 0 ? Obs : 1 ... since i have put this condition nothing happend

Comment: What errors do you see on the console? Is `Obs` a defined variable? And yes, that is __ternary__ not __lambda__.

Comment: Errors in console ? price is defined ? Obs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `? :` operator is not a "lambda expression"; it's the *conditional operator*. The problem is that its precedence is very low so you have to parenthesize it:

```
$(".invoice table tbody").append("\
        <tr> \
          <td> <span class=''>" + (price.toFixed(0) == 0 ? Obs : 1) + "</span></td> \
          <td> <span class=''>" + price.toFixed(2) + "</span> </td> \
          <td> <input type='checkbox' name='removeItem' class='removeItemCheckBox'/></td> \
        </tr> \
");
```

Without the parentheses, the `+` operators on either side would take precedence and the whole expression would be different.

Comment: yes. i have test it. and it works.  the paratheses have resolved the problem.. thank you very much

Comment: Also note that the `price.toFixed(0)` is redundant, and is also causing an implicit type conversion on the comparison.

Comment: Good point: @user2232273 note that `.toFixed(0)` returns a string, not a number; you might be better off using `Math.floor(price)`.

Comment: thanks for your advice. i thought .toFixed returns a number.. i better use then math.floor.. thank your very much